# Seeing AWS PostgreSQL-on-Aurora snapshot sizes of 0 GB - is this normal for a db of ~800mb?

Tags: postgresql, aws-aurora

While working on some code to manage our manual snapshots, I noticed that a number of recent AWS PostgreSQL-on-Aurora snapshots show a storage size of 0 GB (older ones are at 1 gb). I thought it might be rounding in the wrong direction (the database is ~800 meg so far), but I wasnt sure if that was the reason for the 0 size.

I restored one of the snapshots with the intent of confirming that there's usable data in them. I am unable to connect to cluster restored from one of these snapshots despite using the same incoming IP and security group as the production cluster. In fact, I was unable to connect to it even after explicitly adding a SG that contained my IP. I've been using RDS (on "regular" postgres and MSSQL) for many years, so I doubt there is a "noob RDS" issue here - but I wouldnt discount a noob Aurora issue. Apparently I am missing some difference between Aurora (as PostgreSQL) and these other databases - or there's a cluster / instance / database problem that isn't yet revealing itself.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS support responded and indicated that the misleading snapshot size data is a known issue with snapshots for clusters. They intend to fix it, but do not have an ETA on the fix. The connection issue cleared up without making any changes to credentials or other code.